# How to use contents of a string as object name of a class constructor in Java and can I use object of a class more than one times?

Tags: java

I am making a program which will create files and delete files etc. but the program can only create one file and after doing that it gets terminated, so I want to use String as name of create_file class object name so I can increment the numbers(String used as name of the object) so my question is, how can I use String as object name of a class constructor?
below is the source code of the program-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Create_File {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Selecter.select();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    static void create() throws IOException {
        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter a name for your file");
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));){
            name = reader.readLine();
            //this block is used as try with resource statement used to overcome scanner resource leak
        }
        try{
            //file is created with the name that user gives
            
            File obj = new File("D:\\txtfiles\\"+name+".txt");
            if(obj.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("file successfully created with the name "+obj.getName());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The file already exists");
            }
            
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            //here exception during file creation is caught
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      info(name);
        name = null;
//      Selecter.select();
    }
    static void info(String name) throws IOException {
        File obj = new File("D:\\txtfiles\\"+name+".txt");
        String data = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(obj);
        if(obj.exists()) {
                //file properties are printed out for both newly created file and the existing file
                System.out.println("File properties");
                System.out.println("Name of the file = "+obj.getName());
                System.out.println("Path of file = "+obj.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("Size of file in Kb= "+obj.length()/1024); // obj.lengeth is divided by 1024 to get the file size in Kb
                System.out.println("Readable = "+obj.canRead());
                System.out.println("Writable = "+obj.canWrite());
        }
            else {System.out.println("the file does not exist");
            //this block is used as try with resource statement used to overcome scanner resource leak
            while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                data = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println(data);
                }
            }
//      Selecter.select();
        }
    static void delete(String name) throws IOException {
        try{
            File obj = new File("D:\\txtfiles\\"+name+".txt");
        
        obj.delete();
        if(obj.exists()==false) {
            System.out.println("file deleted successfully");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("file does not exist");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

}
```

below is the source code of Selecter class-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
public class Selecter {

    static void select() throws IOException {
        String num=null;
        Create_File create =new Create_File();
        System.out.println("Select Action");
        System.out.println("1. Create new text file");
        System.out.println("2. Delete an existing file");
        System.out.println("3. Find info of a file");
        System.out.println("4. Print the contents of a file");
        System.out.println("5. EXIT");
        System.out.println("Your choice = ");
        
        
        try
            (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));){
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(num= reader.readLine());
            if(choice==1) {
                create.create();
                
            }
            else if(choice == 2){
                System.out.println("enter file name to delete");
                String name=reader.readLine();
                create.delete(name);
            }
        else if(choice == 3) {
            System.out.println("enter file name to find its info");
            String name= reader.readLine();
            create.info(name);
        }
        else if(choice ==4) {
            Buffer contents = new Buffer();
            Buffer.main(null);
        }
        else if(choice == 5) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        
//      select();
    }

}
```

or is there an alternative solution for this problem I want the program to keep running till the user wants to exit.

Comment: *"I want the program to keep running till the user wants to exit"* - Are you just looking for a loop then?  You can wrap your top-level program logic in a loop which will keep checking the user input and performing the requested task.  Or are you asking something else?  It's not entirely clear to me what specifically isn't working as expected.

Comment: hey David, it is in loop all the other options work except for when we select option 1 (create) the second time it gives errors but for other option it works just fine.

Comment: And what is the error?  Which operation produces that error?  Please be specific about the problem.